# distribution derivative in a general case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{H^2_0(\Omega)}$ and $T=(U.\nabla)$ with $U=(\frac{-\partial (f-g)}{\partial y},\frac{\partial (f-g)}{\partial x})$
I want t prove that: 
$$\int_{\Omega}T(\Delta f) (f-g)dx=-\int_{\Omega}\Delta f T(f-g)dx$$

My idea is that we can say that $T$ is a distribution and we derive in the distribution sense

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How is the distribution $T$ defined? Also, what is $(U. \nabla)$?

Comment: $(U.\nabla)$ is the scalar product on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @HachemTouati. $U \cdot \nabla$ looks like an operator, not a distribution.

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you